# How to paste one long line of code to multiple lines in vs code mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

im trying to paste a long line of code but it only pastes to one line, is there a way to pastes it so i dont have to scroll on one line to see the whole code?

```
# putting this here so i can post this question
```

Comment: nevremind, i just used js beautifier:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code just use "Toggle Word Wrap" from the top menu "View", then long lines will wrap visually - it's still one line just displayed so you don't have to scroll left or right.

Here a video describing this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wUJp1UyjY8